# Two matrices whose product is equal to the identity matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I need to multiply two matrices one we call **P type 1x4** another called **Q type 4x1**

I cannot find values that will give me an identity matrix as a result when I **multiply PQ together**.

**Where zeros are not allowed.**

Comment: $PQ $ or $QP\, $?

Comment: Please add any working you have already done - we are not here to just answer homework questiions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $P=(1\;1\;1\;1)$ and $Q=\frac14^{\mathrm t\!}P$.